# Publish extension using launchWebAuthFlow api

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Hello my extension has OAuth2 authentication with Google and is not being approved by the Microsoft Partner Center because I use the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` api and it needs a redirect URI, which is retrieved through `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()`, where the extension ID is part of the URI and it is necessary to authorize it to display the consent screen. The microsoft team does not approve the extension because it says that it does not open. Obviously it will not open because when the extension is opened in dev mode, it generates a new ID and it is not approved.

**Has anyone experienced this problem?**

My extension: https://www.passbrow.com

Comment: Do you want to port the extension to Edge Chromium? You could refer to [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension) and [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension) about how to port Chrome extension to Edge Chromium and how to publish an extension on Microsoft Edge Addons. If the issue still exists, please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: In the documentation he talks about adding peculiarities to the notes.  I added this information to the publication notes and published it again.  I will wait for the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to come back if the issue still exists.

Comment: After add info in the notes, it’s approved!

Comment: Great! You could put the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, insert in the note field when clicking on publish, the extension ID that is released for the consent screen.  Your extension will already have the ID even without being published, you can find it on the home screen of the extension's dashboard.